# How to access clipboard data programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, macos

How is it possible to access clipboard data on the Mac programmatically?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apple has a [Pasteboard Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008099) the main class you are looking for is [NSPasteboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSPasteboard)

The example for reading strings is

```
NSPasteboard *pasteboard = <#Get a pasteboard#>; 
NSArray *classes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSString class], nil];
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionary];
NSArray *copiedItems = [pasteboard readObjectsForClasses:classes options:options];
if (copiedItems != nil) {
    // Do something with the contents...
```